# getting a rotated image in my image view after taking from the camera as a portrait one

Tags: image, email, camera, image-gallery

My requirement is to take picture from the camera or pick a image from the gallery and show it in a image view.. After showing the image I'm sending as a mail whatever the image is selected. My issues is every time i take a portrait picture form the camera it rotates and show it in the image view. How to fix this issue.

thanks in advance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.skicka_bild_activity);

        share = new Sharedprefs(SkickaBild.this);

        emailSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.skicka_button);
        emailSendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        emailSendButton.setEnabled(false);

        Button camaraOnButtton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fotografera_button);
        camaraOnButtton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button galleryOpenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.valj_bild_button);
        galleryOpenButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        imageSetImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_skick);

        maxWidth = share.getmaxwidth();

        mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.skicka_button:

            if (isImageViewFilled) {

                showEmailComposer();
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        SkickaBild.this);
                builder.setTitle("Alert !!");
                builder.setMessage("Pick a image before you send the email")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

            break;

        case R.id.fotografera_button:

            share.setisFromTabsClearImage(false);
            String fileName = "temp.jpg";
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
            mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    mCapturedImageURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);

            break;
        case R.id.valj_bild_button:

            share.setisFromTabsClearImage(false);

            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);

            break;
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mCapturedImageURI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String capturedImageFilePath = cursor
                        .getString(column_index_data);

                Bitmap mImageBitmap = BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath);
                imageSetImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);

                isImageViewFilled = true;

                if (isImageViewFilled) {
                    emailSendButton.setEnabled(true);

                    emailSendButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.skicka_button_black));

                }

                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                if (root.canWrite()) {
                    System.out.println("PICTURE PATH " + capturedImageFilePath);
                    pic = new File(capturedImageFilePath);

                    String cPath = pic.getAbsolutePath();


                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cPath, bmOptions);
                    float photoW = mImageBitmap.getWidth();
                    float photoH = mImageBitmap.getHeight();

                    // Get the dimensions of the View
                    float targetW = Float.parseFloat(maxWidth);
                    float targetH = (photoH / photoW) * targetW;

                    System.out.println("cam bitmap height"
                            + mImageBitmap.getHeight());
                    System.out.println("cam bitmap weidth" + maxWidth);

                    System.out.println("cam bitmap Width 02 "
                            + mImageBitmap.getWidth());

                    System.out.println("cam target Height " + targetH);
                    System.out.println("cam target width " + targetW);

                                    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = (int) scaleFactor;
                    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cPath, bmOptions);
                    mImageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                            (int) targetW, (int) targetH, false);

                    FileOutputStream fout;
                    try {
                        fout = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                        mImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                fout);
                        fout.flush();
                        fout.close();
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                InputStream in = null;
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                try {

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                    System.out.println("PICTUREPATH" + picturePath);
                    cursor.close();

                    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

                    int orientation = getOrientation(this, selectedImage);
                    System.out.println("ORIENTATION VALUE " + orientation);
                    imageSetImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                    isImageViewFilled = true;

                    if (isImageViewFilled) {

                        emailSendButton.setEnabled(true);

                        emailSendButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.skicka_button_black));

                    }

                    // ////////////////////////// Image is set ///////////////

                    pic = new File(picturePath);

                    String cPath = pic.getAbsolutePath();
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cPath, bmOptions);
                    float photoW = imageBitmap.getWidth();
                    float photoH = imageBitmap.getHeight();

                    // Get the dimensions of the View
                    float targetW = Float.parseFloat(maxWidth);
                    float targetH = (photoH / photoW) * targetW;

                    System.out.println(" bitmap height"
                            + imageBitmap.getHeight());
                    System.out.println(" bitmap weidth" + maxWidth);

                    System.out.println(" bitmap Width 02 "
                            + imageBitmap.getWidth());

                    System.out.println(" target Height " + targetH);
                    System.out.println(" target width " + targetW);

                                        float scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH
                            / targetH);

                    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = (int) scaleFactor;
                    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cPath, bmOptions);
                    imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                            (int) targetW, (int) targetH, false);

                    FileOutputStream fout;

                    fout = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
                    fout.flush();
                    fout.close();

                    bitmap.recycle();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            break;
        }

    }

    public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri photoUri) {
        String[] orientationColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                orientationColumn, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }


    private void showEmailComposer() {

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { share.getMailTo() });

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, share.getsubject());

        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic));
        // email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pic.getName());
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, share.getemailbody());

        email.setType("message/rfc822");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

        isEmailSend = true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        System.out.println("ON RESUME INCOMING CHECK");

        if (share.getisFromTabsClearImage()) {

            imageSetImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ingenbildvald));

            emailSendButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.skicka_button));

            emailSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            share.setisFromTabsClearImage(false);

        }
        if (isEmailSend) {

            imageSetImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ingenbildvald));

            emailSendButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.skicka_button));
            emailSendButton.setEnabled(false);

            isEmailSend = false;
        }
    }
```